# neo4j StatementResult to json in scala

Tags: json, scala, neo4j

I'm new to scala. I'm building a REST-API to query several services, one of them Neo4j, using scala-2.11
I'm reading a neo4j output as StatementResult (org.neo4j.driver.v1 public interface StatementResult extends Iterator), 
this way:

```
val recordsList = session.run(queryNeo4j)
println("recordsList:" +recordsList.list())
```

The println gives this output:

> recordsList:[Record<{n: node<6103>}>, Record<{n: node<6104>}>]

and trying to convert it into a json to send in the response, using play-json.
At first, I've tried this:

```
val recordJ = Json.parse(recordList)
```

but it's not working.
I've also tried this:

```
while (recordsList.hasNext() ) {
          val record = recordsList.next()
          println("record: " +record)
          val recordJ = Json.parse(record)
        }
```

But it's not working either.I get this error:

```
error: overloaded method value parse with alternatives:
   [INFO]   (input: Array[Byte])play.api.libs.json.JsValue <and>
   [INFO]   (input: java.io.InputStream)play.api.libs.json.JsValue <and>
   [INFO]   (input: String)play.api.libs.json.JsValue
   [INFO]  cannot be applied to (org.neo4j.driver.v1.Record)
   [INFO]           val recordJ = Json.parse(record)
   [INFO]
```

Could someone please help me to get a json with the recordsList?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to turn the statement result into a deep list of objects.

`val data = result.list(_.asMap())`

And then format the result as JSON.

See the javadocs for each method.

- [StatementResult](http://neo4j.com/docs/api/java-driver/current/org/neo4j/driver/v1/StatementResult.html#list-org.neo4j.driver.v1.util.Function-)
- [Record](http://neo4j.com/docs/api/java-driver/current/org/neo4j/driver/v1/Record.html#asMap--)

Comment: Hello, I have this error with your solution: error: value list is not a member of List[org.neo4j.driver.v1.Record]
[ERROR]       val data = recordsList.list(_.asMap()

Comment: My code:                                                                                                   
 val recordsList = Neo4jGraph.getGraph(label, session)
  val data = recordsList.list(_.asMap())